# how do i transform a column of data frame while keeping the remaining data frame same in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe for example

```
df.show()
+---+-----+
|age| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|Alice|
|  2|  Bob|
|  4| Bill|
+---+-----+
```

now i want to transform in such a way that name column becomes struct type with two columns 'name_id' which can 0 for all values for now and 'name_text' which is values in name column.
Note: df can change. so i cannot hard code the schema. it has to be dynamic. 
so for example if i need a fuction such that

```
func(df)
```

should give a df as

```
+---+---------+
|age|     name|
+---+---------+
|  1|[0,Alice]|
|  2|  [0,Bob]|
|  4| [0,Bill]|
+---+---------+
```

this would be a huge help thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def generate_intial_transform_schema(df,column_id):
    index= 0
    schemaList = []
    for schema in df.schema:
        if index == column_id:
            schemaList.append(
            StructField(schema.name,StructType([
                StructField("value",schema.dataType,schema.nullable),
                StructField("id",schema.dataType,True),
                ]),True))
        else:
            schemaList.append(schema)
        index += 1
    generated_schema = StructType(schemaList)
    return generated_schema

def intial_transform(lines,column_id):

    return_touple = ()
    for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
        if i!= column_id:
            return_touple = return_touple+(lines[i],)
        else:
            return_touple = return_touple+((lines[i],1),)
    return return_touple
```

so, you call the map function

```
df2 = df1.rdd.map(
lambda lines:intial_transform(lines,1)
).toDF(
generate_intial_transform_schema(lines,1)
)
```